Do you say "don't play with fire" to a person who is playing with something that might get him dirty?
My son is throwing rocks into a pond with dirty black water and if the rock is pretty big it might splash the water all over the place and the water might get his clothes dirty.
Can I say  to him "don't play with fire"?
Normally, that phrase is used when you are playing with a sharp knife, which my hurt you, or you might lose your job with you argue with your boss.
But, is "don't play with fire" suitable for the above situation (get clothes dirty)?
If not, what are other similar phrases I can use?

Not really.  The idiom "to play with fire" refers to something that is very dangerous or risky.

Fire is dangerous, and mud is not.

Only if getting his clothes dirty would awaken someone's wrath.

If you want an alternative, then use something like "Be careful! You'll get dirty!".   That would be a natural way to warn a child, without traumatising them.

Come on, please stop asking these questions which seemed designed to trip us up and are not really very good.

What @Lambie said. Collins has a typical definition: If you say that someone is playing with fire, you mean that they are doing something dangerous that may result in great harm for them and cause many problems. Surely if you read that, you wouldn't need to ask about it here.

@FumbleFingers That;s 100% accurate. Getting dirty water on you from throwing rocks into the water ain't dangerous.

@Lambie: Unless getting his clothes dirty would awaken someone's wrath, as TimR says. OR if he was using some mains electricity device, in which case getting wet could lead to a fatal electric shock.

@FumbleFingers It does not matter. The expression would not apply. There's nothing in the question about anything like that. If we don't provide the usual limits to usual expressions, it just becomes ridiculous. What TimR means is Don't poke the bear. Making your dad angry is playing with fire. So, it's the father that poses the danger. Not the action of the kid throwing rocks....

Please show your research. This phrase is not only for knives (or fire). I disagree with some of the comments here because getting muddy could be "disastrous" within the scope of the context, and the meaning of the phrase is simply "don't take chances." But IMO this question does not currently meet site guidelines because 1) you wondered whether something was ok, 2) explained why you thought it might not be (many questions miss this step, but 3) asked, without looking it up (or if you did, mentioning it).

@AndyBonner, How can you assume that a learner can use a word in a right context even he can understand the meaning of that word. Suppose you learn Chinese, you can understand the meaning of a Chinese word but not sure if that word can be used in some situations, you will ask Chinese people for clarity.

Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. When I mentioned "context" I was saying "I think this phrase is ok for this context." But the rest is: you should know by now that to ask "Is this ok," you should also show some research, even if that research didn't solve your problem. This isn't because SE wants to make people do work, but so that if there was a flaw or misunderstanding with the sources you found, that can be addressed.

I have heard the phrase you're playing with fire used to mean "If you keep  doing what you're doing, and what I've warned you may happen does indeed happen, you're going to be in big trouble. Don't test me. You won't like the punishment."
Imagine two brothers roughhousing indoors, and mom tells them to stop because they might knock a lamp or a vase over. They settle down for a while but soon they're back at it. Mom gives them another warning and this time she tells them that they're "playing with fire". It's a warning to them that easygoing mom might transform into dragon mom.
It also has a judgmental meaning when  person A says it to person B about person C. Person C is doing something risky.

She's playing with fire, that one. No good will come of it.


I think that idiom is a little too strong for the situation you describe. When you caution someone about playing with fire, it usually implies harm or strife that is more serious than getting dirty water on you.
If he was throwing rocks at an alligator in the pond, then I think that might raise it to the level of playing with fire.
Instead, I might say:

If you throw a big rock in there, it might splash that dirty black water all over your brand new white sweatshirt that Santa paid $60 for.

I'm joking a bit, but I think it's usually best to say what you really mean so there's no room for confusion.
Nevertheless, to answer your question, you might say:

You're tempting fate.

Very informal:

Don't do the crime if you can't do the time.
Play stupid games, win stupid prizes.

Or, from a different angle:

What goes up must come down.

And then after it happens:

You made your bed, now lie in it.

